# Custom Component Xamarin Binding Command with Parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding, parameters, command

I created a Xamarin Component with two BindableProperties.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty AddToCartCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AddToCartCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ICommand), default(ICommand), BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty AddToCartCommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AddToCartCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(object), default(object), BindingMode.TwoWay);

 public ProductCurve()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        prezzo_nuovo.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("AddToCartCommand", source: this));
        prezzo_nuovo.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("AddToCartCommandParameter"));
    }
```

I would like to pass parameters to the Command, so:

```
   <componenti:ProductCurve 
                                            x:Name="productElement"
                                            WidthRequest="180" 
                                            ShowPromo ="{Binding ArticoloPromozionale}" 
                                            AddToCartCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ItemPriceClickCommand, Source={x:Reference home}}"
                                            AddToCartCommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                            Prezzo="{Binding prezzoLordo, StringFormat='€{0:0.00}'}"
                                            PrezzoVecchio="{Binding prezzoOriginaleL, StringFormat='€{0:0.00}'}"
                                            DescrizioneProdotto="{Binding descart}"
                                            Immagine="{Binding Path=MiniImage}"/>
```

In the linked ViewModel, i have subscribed the Command

```
  public Command ItemPriceClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemPriceCommand ?? (this.itemPriceCommand = new  Command(this.ItemPriceClick));
        }
    }
```

but it's doesn't work. There is a way to send object in ItemPriceClick(object attached)?

This is the method ItemPriceClick:

```
 private async void ItemPriceClick(object attachedObject)
    {
        try
        {
            // Differenziare il tipo di click
            if (attachedObject is ArticoloCatalogo articolo)
            {
                await CarrelloManager.Instance.AddCarrello(articolo);
            }
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CartItemCount));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }
```

For now, the attachedObject is always null.

Comment: what does not work exactly? how is defined `ItemPriceClick`?

Comment: This is the method ItemPriceClick:

 private async void ItemPriceClick(object attachedObject)
    {
        try
        {
            // Differenziare il tipo di click
            if (attachedObject is ArticoloCatalogo articolo)
            {
                await CarrelloManager.Instance.AddCarrello(articolo);
            }
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CartItemCount));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }
For now, the attachedObject is always null.

Comment: Hi, where do you want to send object in `ItemPriceClick(object attached)`? Sorry, not too much understanding what your needs. And what is the `componenti:ProductCurve`? You explain more logic of the function or share some image.

Comment: ProductCurve is a ContentView. In ProductCurve i have defined BindableProperty AddToCartCommand. The goal is when AddToCartCommand is called, AddToCartCommandParameter is passed as parameters in function.

Comment: @GianmarcoTanzi Okey, could you share the full code of `ProductCurve` and its `Xaml` code. It seems not needs to add bindable property for  `ProductCurve` if it already contains a `Button` control, you could bind command for it from ViewModel directly.